# Grep-like filter in C?

Tags: c, regex

Is there any simple way to filter out a string in C using regular expressions?

Here is example how an invocation of such function `re(regexp,str,outstr)` could look like:

```
printf("%s\n", re("G*o", "Geraldo Gerardo German", outstr));
```

and will fill `outstr` with "Geraldo Gerardo".

What is the most appropriate way to do it in C? To write my own function or to use an existed one (hope, multi-platform, so ANSI or any portable standard lib is preferable).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725630/regular-expressions-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a POSIX world, `#include <regex.h>` should lead you to the [standard POSIX regex library](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/POSIX-Regexp-Compilation.html#POSIX-Regexp-Compilation)

Comment: +1 For the non-sledgehammer approach. PCRE's backreferences are nice, but preclude a NFA or DFA matching algorithm as described at http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: @Dave The downside is that POSIX is not portable

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you want to deploy on windows, there's [Regex for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/regex.htm), a direct port of `regex.h` to windows. Otherwise, posix lives almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want portability then you should use a regex library written in portable C. For example [PCRE](http://pcre.org/). There is no regular expression support in the C standard library so you have to look outside that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) or [re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) (the latter requiring a C wrapper). However, I don't know that using the output of such a function directly in `printf` is a good idea. What if there's no match? (Also your regex would not match that string. You probably meant `"G.*o"`)

Answer (score 1):

*regular-expressions* are not part of any ANSI C, so you'll need to rely on some 3rd party lib.

Here are two, I'd recommend PCRE:

1. [Regular Expressions - The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Regular-Expressions.html)
2. [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a C-wrapper around Boost.Regex:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html